# Changing the CSS properties of specific elements in a div class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the text about the image to move to the right hand side of the image rather go under the image, I have been experimenting with `float: right`, but this moves all of the elements in the div class known as info, therefore I was wondering if there was a way to apply CSS formatting to specific elements of a div class?

```css
.info {
  color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <h3>Info</h3>
  <img src="img.jpg" alt="Image" width="70px" height="113px">
  <p>Information on the image
    <p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important here is selecting img, and floating it left, so text on the right will by floating around `img`. To select element inside `<div>` with class name `.info`, simply add it after space

`.info img {float: left}`

```css
.info {
  color: #888;
  width: 250px;
}
.info img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <h3>Info</h3>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/70x113" alt="Image">
  <p>Dolor blanditiis cum obcaecati quibusdam mollitia modi. Accusamus error culpa quaerat aliquam doloremque Deserunt sit vel corrupti repellat quod animli est impedit? Adipisci sit magni recusandae quod quaerat.<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Umm, if i were to use the box model it will work as normal in the .info area right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: As in if added some padding, border, margin etc to the div class info it would also be added to the image in the div class, right?

Comment: No. You have to add `padding`, `margin` etc. (most of declarations) to elements separately.  `.class element{...}`. (Yes, for `color`, `font` and so on.)

Comment: Inherited_properties -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance#Inherited_properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS tag selector to set the image to float left like so:

```
.info img 
{
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
<style>
        .info {
            color: #eaeaea;
        }
        .info img{
            float: left;
        }
            .info p {
                float: right;
            }
    </style>
<div class="info">
        <h3>Info</h3>
        <img src="img.jpg" alt="Image" width="70" height="113">
        <p>Information on the image</p>
    </div>
```

Now image is on the left side and text on the right side.
This is what you want?